# Allocating space for an empty list in python in O(1) time

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have a situation where I have a determinate input range and as such, am able to do indexing entirely in O(1) by creating a list that is the size of the range of the input and indexing the input by itself. To be clearer, I essentially have the following situation

```
a = "inputrange"
rng = ord(max(a)) - ord(min(s))
data = [None] * rng
```

My issue is, I'm not sure if the allocation process for `data` is O(1) or not. Intuitively, there should be some way to do it in O(1), as on the stack I'm simply defining a start and end point for the data, and as such should only take O(1) time to allocate, but python is a bit removed from this so I can't be sure.

It's very important I can allocate in O(1), as I am creating a suffix tree for the input data, and so to ensure O(1) indexing when traversing the tree I need a list the size of the alphabet (or a hashmap, although I'm avoiding those), but since I'm allocating essentially for every suffix, I need allocating to be constant.

Another idea I had was to create a "template" list and copy that over, but copying takes O(n) time so that won't work.

EDIT: This isn't a duplicate of "what is the time complexity of `[var]*n`", I *clearly* state I am looking for a way to do to list memory allocation in O(1). Just because I happen to be using `[var]*n` as my current method of allocating this memory, does not mean it is answered by knowing the complexity of this method.

The question still remains: **Is there a way of allocating space for an empty list in python in O(1) time**

Comment: The allocation should be O(1). It knows exactly how big it needs to be from the multiplciation, so it doesn't need to grow it incrementally.

Comment: Note that even though the memory allocation is O(1), putting `None` into each element is O(n).

Comment: You really need to stop thinking of Python `list` objects as C primitive arrays. `[None] * rng` is a linear time operation. But there is no getting around that. Alternatively, consider `numpy` and `numpy.empty`

Comment: Again, **there is not way to do what you want with Python lists**. There is no concept of "memory allocation", you are creating a list object. If you need that list object to be a certain size, it will *always* require an O(N) operation, where `N` is the size of that list. Note, `[None]*n` is *not empty* (unless `n ==0`), `[]` is an empty list, `[None, None, None]` is not